# How to call method save() in a Django model class using attr string name?

Tags: python, django

For example in my code:

```
class ClassName():
    [...]
    image_bigger = models.ImageField(upload_to='dir', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    image_big = models.ImageField(upload_to='dir', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    image_medium = models.ImageField(upload_to='dir', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    image_small = models.ImageField(upload_to='dir', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    def create_resized(self, attr_name, resized_size):
        [...]

        if attr_name == "bigger":
            self.bigger.save(filename, suf, save=False)
        elif attr_name == "big":
            self.big.save(filename, suf, save=False)
        elif attr_name == "medium":
            self.medium.save(filename, suf, save=False)
        elif attr_name == "small":
            self.small.save(filename, suf, save=False)
```

I'm wondering if there is something like getattr to avoid that ugly if elif block of code...

Comment: if `attr_name == "small"` you really want to save `self.medium`?

Comment: ok Nigel Tufnel it was a bug. Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not to use getattr/hasattr calls? You can write something like this:

```
full_attr_name = 'image_' + attr_name
if hasattr(self, full_attr_name):
    getattr(self, full_attr_name).save(filename, suf, save=False)
```

Hope, you have caught the idea.

Comment: Hemm no... and where is save() method?

Comment: sorry for missing; believe getattr(self, full_attr_name).save(filename, suf, save=False) should work for you

Answer (score 0):

If your having images of different sizes then I think using sorl-thumbnail would have been a better approach. Link attached.

http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#model-examples